# Robot Framework: Is there any way to re-initialize variables which depend on other variable initiallized during test execution

Tags: global-variables, robotframework

I have two global variables with the following default value:

```
${APP_INSTALL_DIR} = "%{ProgramFiles(x86)}\\application_name"
${APP_LAUNCH_PATH} = "${APP_INSTALL_DIR}\\app.exe"
```

These variables first initialized at test launch.

Then I re-initialize `${APP_INSTALL_DIR}` variable during test execution with `C:\\Folder\\application_name` value using `Set Global Variable` keyword.

Is there any way to re-initialize `${APP_LAUNCH_PATH}` variable automatically?

Now when `${APP_INSTALL_DIR}` is changed, `${APP_LAUNCH_PATH}` is not changed and has initial value `%{ProgramFiles(x86)}\\application_name\\app.exe`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to have variables automatically updated when other variables change.

What you can do instead is create a custom keyword that changes all the variables at once.

```
*** Keywords ***
| Reset app directory
| | [Arguments] | ${path}
| | Set global variable | ${APP_INSTALL_DIR} | ${path}
| | Set global variable | ${APP_LAUNCH_PATH} | ${APP_INSTALL_DIR}\\app.exe
```